# WinRT animation doesn't show intermediate values

Tags: .net, xaml, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In WinRT, many animations simply do not show any of the intermediate values, or only show them if you move your mouse or some other system event occurs, strangely.  At the end of the animations, the values are set correctly, but during execution (the 2 second duration of the animation in my case), the intermediate values are never displayed.

After 2 seconds the window disappears but you don't see it flipping when you press X.  SOMETIMES if you move your mouse during the animation, you can see it, but that usually only happens when the XAML graph is more complex.

Here's the XAML:

```html
<Grid Background="#525252">
        <Grid x:Name="AnimatedDialog"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection />
            </Grid.Projection>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#2E2E2E"
                    BorderThickness="1" />

            <Border Background="#2E2E2E" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="10,5"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontSize="20"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Text="{Binding Title,
                                      ElementName=Root,
                                      FallbackValue='This is the title'}" />
            <Border Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="40"
                    Height="40"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="#BD0000"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    PointerReleased="CloseBorder_OnPointerReleased" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                       FontSize="22"
                       Foreground="White"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Text="❌" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Width="550"
                       Height="360"
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="22"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Text="Bacon ipsum dolor amet boudin ground round drumstick porchetta prosciutto spare ribs short ribs bresaola leberkas hamburger sirloin shank tri-tip turkey strip steak. Rump boudin shank, ham hock bresaola shankle shoulder. Alcatra landjaeger kevin tail hamburger turducken flank pork. Meatloaf turducken leberkas, pig sausage pancetta ground round. Beef kevin swine tongue ham hock bacon shoulder leberkas kielbasa rump capicola ribeye chicken shankle venison. Biltong ball tip prosciutto, t-bone cow pork ribeye pancetta strip steak jowl ham drumstick landjaeger short ribs andouille. Turducken tail shankle bacon, pork turkey filet mignon ham pig."
                       TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And code behind:

```csharp
        private void CloseBorder_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Spin AnimatedDialog to close.

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();

            var projection = AnimatedDialog.Projection as PlaneProjection;
            projection.CenterOfRotationY = 0.5;

            var flipAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(flipAnim, projection);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(flipAnim, "RotationX");

            // 2 second flip
            flipAnim.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
            flipAnim.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn};
            flipAnim.From = 0;
            flipAnim.To = 90;

            storyboard.Children.Add(flipAnim);

            storyboard.Completed += StoryboardOnCompleted;

            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        private void StoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, object o)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Completed storyboard.");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, it works when you use a value close to zero, but not actually zero.

```
        private void CloseBorder_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Spin AnimatedDialog to close.

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();

            var projection = AnimatedDialog.Projection as PlaneProjection;
            projection.CenterOfRotationY = 0.5;
            projection.RotationX = .0000000001;  // <--- this line changed

            var flipAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(flipAnim, projection);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(flipAnim, "RotationX");

            // 2 second flip
            flipAnim.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
            flipAnim.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn };
            flipAnim.From = projection.RotationX;  // <--- this line changed
            flipAnim.To = 90;

            storyboard.Children.Add(flipAnim);

            storyboard.Completed += StoryboardOnCompleted;

            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        private void StoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, object o)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Completed storyboard.");
        }
```

Comment: For me adding that line makes no difference.  I suspect you're moving the mouse (read the original question more closely).  Can you try keeping the mouse still after clicking the X?  Please try a few times and let me know what happens.

Comment: I'm not moving the mouse. I did exactly what you asked and I did see it flip without animating. However, my implementation has 2 changed lines, and it's been working 100% of the time without moving the mouse. Please look at the comments in the code to see what changed.

Comment: I changed both lines actually, but it still only works when you move the mouse.  Are you absolutely certain you're keeping the mouse still while clicking?

Comment: OK, I mistyped the second line, and you're right, it works if you do it this way.  This is pretty strange, indeed.  I've submitted it to Microsoft Connect, maybe they can give a better explanation.  Thanks, I'm marking this as the solution.

Comment: Also noticed, if you use `DoubleAnimationWithKeyFrames` instead of `DoubleAnimation`, you only need to change the first line.  Also, animating from 90 to 0 always works, just not 0 (exactly) to 90.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flipAnim.EnableDependentAnimation = true;` and it'll work.

Comment: It doesn't, sorry.  I'm aware of dependent animations, and this isn't one.

Comment: I've created a new project with your code and as soon as I added EnableDependentAnimation the dialog flipped.

Comment: If you move the mouse, it indeed might flip.  Other system events seem to kick start the animation, too.  That's part of the original question.  After you click the X, try not moving your mouse at all, and do it a few times, then let me know the result.  Thanks!

Comment: You're right, if I don't move the mouse cursor the animation doesn't happen either. I tried several things but I've no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Yup, and if moving the mouse usually doesn't work for me on this example.  Frankly, I'm seeing this exact behavior on very many animations in WinRT.  I think it's a bug and have submitted it as such on Microsoft Connect.